# body.getAsync() returns unexpected characters on Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Outlook 2016 for Windows.

I'm using the function `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` to get the email contents:

```js
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("mailbox", 1.3)) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", function (result) {
        if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            var htmlBody = result.value;
            globalAddin.setLocalStorageItem('htmlEmailBody', htmlBody);
            globalAddin.getEmailSignature(htmlBody);
            window.location =
                globalAddin.randomizeUrl("composeemail/add_contact.html");
        }
    });
}
```

This is working with Outlook for the web and Outlook 2013 for Windows:

[image]

With Outlook 2016 for Windows, it succeeds but returns unknown characters `ÿþ<` in value field:

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's strange , I use this function and it's well on Outlook 2016 for desktop. You try maybe to update outlook /try another computer or something like this?

Comment: What is the full version (version and build) of Outlook you are seeing this on?

Comment: thanks. I upgraded to latest version and added a trial account. It work after that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try upgrade latest version and right license. I resolved it after install latest version and add a 365 trial account.